# Обращение к объекту из другого потока

Tags: c#, activex, многопоточность

Появилась кривая задача - использовать ActiveX компонент без формы. Натолкнулся на решение похожей проблемы. У меня получился такой примерно код:

```
public class C
{
    private AxMsRdpClient9NotSafeForScripting rdp;
    private Thread thread;

    public void B()
    {
        rdp.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate
        {
            rdp.Connect();
        }));           
    }

    public void A()
    {
        thread = new Thread((ThreadStart)
            delegate
            {
                Console.WriteLine("I'm from thread");
                rdp = new AxMsRdpClient9NotSafeForScripting();
                rdp.BeginInit();
                rdp.CreateControl();

                //прочая инициализация

                Application.Run();
            });

        thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
        thread.IsBackground = true;
        thread.Start();
    }
}
```

Ну так вот, в методе B выбрасывается исключение "Невозможно вызвать Invoke или BeginInvoke для элемента управления до завершения создания дескриптора окна." Проверяю условия rdp.IsHandleCreated - всегда false. Что делать?

Comment: Зачастую в данном кейсе причина заключается, что отсутствует добавление контрола в Controls

Answer (score 1):

Наследует ли `AxMsRdpClient9NotSafeForScripting` от `Control`? Если нет - то создайте в отдельном потоке пустой `Control` (сохранять его никуда не нужно). Если да - то ничего делать не надо.

После этого в дочернем потоке можно взять `SynchronizationContext.Current`, сохранить и использовать в дальнейшем вместо метода `Invoke`.